# Trait that counts instances of class

Tags: php, oop, traits

I have a trait that I would like to make so I can easily count and retrieve all the instances of the class.
I know I need to push it to an array, but I don't know how I should "store" the array. Do I use public, private, static, etc?

```
trait Countable
{
  public $all = array();

  public function addToObjects()
  {
    //do stuff
    $this->all[] = $this->somekindofproperty;
  }

}
```

I want to be able to something like the following.

```
$c = new MyClass;
$objects = $c->all();
```

Pretty much each class with this trait should have it's own array.

Comment: when you say "all the instances of the class" is it the class in witch you defined the method or it's some others classes too?

Comment: all the classes that have the trait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i defined a `trait` with name `counter` and used it in a class for storing objects.

```
trait Counter
{
    public static $all = array();
    public static function addToObjects($object)
    {
        if (is_object($object))
        {
            self::$all[] = $object;
        }
    }

}
class CountingClass
{
    use Counter;
}
class MyClass
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        CountingClass::addToObjects($this);
    }
}

$c = new MyClass;
$c = new MyClass;
$c = new MyClass;
$c = new MyClass;

print_r(CountingClass::$all);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => MyClass Object
        (
        )

    [1] => MyClass Object
        (
        )

    [2] => MyClass Object
        (
        )

    [3] => MyClass Object
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I wanted. I want the the array to be appended to when ever a new instance of the class is created. I don't want to add the object manually each time.

Comment: @CriticalTheWizard Is this you want?

Comment: Yeah I think that did it. I didn't know about `self`, so that is why I was probably having troubles.